# Using IN to search an database with an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_events WHERE userID =" . $uid . " OR groupID = (IN ($gId) WHERE userID IS NULL) ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```

This looks like this when printed:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user_events WHERE userID = 34 OR groupID =(IN (44,45) WHERE uID IS NULL) ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

What I'm trying to do is select from the database any row where either the `userId` matches a specific variable or where the `groupID` matches a CSV variable where the `userID` is `NULL`.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here? I'm quite stuck!

Comment: Use `IN` as an operator when dealing with comma-separated lists. Use `=` as an operator when comparing exact values. Use `LIKE` as an operator when comparing case-insensitive values and wildcards. They are all ***comparison operators*** and should be used as such (just like in mathematics).

Comment: Also, use prepared statements, don't concatenate strings to build a query.

Comment: If you use [placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php), a lot of the SQL query encoding issues will be handled for you. Seeing things like `$uid` inside a query should set your hair on fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_events 
       WHERE userID =" . $uid . " 
       OR (groupID IN ($gId) AND userID IS NULL) ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```

Answer (score 9):

`IN` is an operator, not a... that. You also want `AND`, not `WHERE`.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_events
        WHERE userID = $uid
           OR groupID IN ($gId) AND userID IS NULL
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM user_events 
WHERE (userID = 34 OR groupID IN (44,45)) and uID IS NULL
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

In PHP, this might look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_events WHERE (userID =". $uid . " OR groupID IN ($gId)) AND userID IS NULL ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```